# Export to xml in from p:dataTable is not working

Tags: xml, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with PrimeFaces. I can't export any data from datatable to xml file. On each try I am getting same error:
 `javax.faces.FacesException: No suitable xml tag found for org.primefaces.component.column.Column@79879de5`

Code of datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="Codes" var="code" value="#{codesTable.allCodesFromDB}" selection="#{codesTable.selectedCodes}" rowKey="#{code.id}"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}
           {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
        rowSelectMode="checkbox"
        paginator="true" rows="15" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
        <div class="inline-block">
            <h:commandLink>
                <img src="resource/img/csv-icon.png" alt="" class="exporter-icon img-responsive"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="Codes" fileName="kody" selectionOnly="true"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block">
            <h:commandLink>
                <img src="resource/img/xml-icon.png" alt="" class="exporter-icon img-responsive"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="Codes" fileName="kody2" selectionOnly="true" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </div>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>
    <p:column sortBy="#{code.id}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Id" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{code.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{code.code}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Kod"/>
        </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{code.code}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{code.companyName}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Nazwa firmy" />
        </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{code.companyName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{code.codesQuantity}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Ilość" />
        </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{code.codesQuantity}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{code.formattedStringOfDate}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Data" />
        </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{code.formattedStringOfDate}" />
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton process="Codes" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Usuń" actionListener="#{codesTable.removeCodesFromDB()}"
                update=":tableDataFormCodes:Codes"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

CSV export is normally working and when I try to export XML with no rows selected, program is generating file.
I tried newest version and 5.2, both are not working.
I am using glassfish server.

Comment: Showcase works. Try that locally

Comment: Actually it is only locally and still same problem when I try to export any row.

Comment: just a thought: can you try by using some latin characters instead of `Ilość` as header?

Comment: Unfortunately still same error.

Comment: the problem is with the selection column. `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>`. remove it and it should work or add a facet header to it.

Comment: Now it is working. Very thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the selection column.

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>.
```

remove it and it should work or add a facet header to it.

See the source code [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/XMLExporter.java)